# Perfectly matching concentric shell walls?

Tags: modifiers

I have built two concentric hemispherical shells from two spheres centered at (x,y,z) = (0,0,0), and added a thickness to the outside shell to fill the gap between the two shells. However, I have found that -- despite the shells being of the same proportionality (height = 1/2 diameter) -- I do not get a perfect intersection of the inner wall of the green shell and the wall of the blue shell, as illustrated below.

[image]
Am I misinterpreting what I'm seeing? How can I make the inner wall of the thickened green shell exactly match the boundary of the (smaller) blue shell? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Its not a good idea to have two different visible surfaces (faces) in the same exact position.  The results are not acceptable to most people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the two meshes in object mode.  Then in edit mode you you can select the two edge and perform a Bridge Edge Loop.  That will also serve as a check to make sure you have the same number of vertices.

If you want two separate objects. You could start with one hemisphere, [solidify modifier], apply the modifier,  The select the inner portion and menu [separate] to form two separate meshes.

Comment: Thank you! Your last suggestion is exactly what I was looking for.